# p:gmap not rendering inside a h:form tag

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The map does not render when I add the  tag. When I remove the tag, the map renders. Please assist.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title></title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="base.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:gmap
            center="#{initParam['centerLatitude']}, #{initParam['centerLongitude']}"
            zoom="#{initParam['centerZoom']}" type="map"
            style="width:100%;height:100%" model="#{mapBean.mapModel}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{mapBean.onMarkerSelect}" event="overlaySelect" />
        </p:gmap>
    </h:form>
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#{initParam['googleApiKey']}&amp;callback=initMap"></script>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: By adding PrimeFaces 7 in the title you sort of suggest it works in 6.0 and 6.1. Does it? And did you inspect the client side html? And did you try removing the css (for all we know there is a `form { display: none}` in there ? And.... Please investigate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I change from 100% height in the style tag to 600px, the map displayed again. The issue seems to be with a 100% height.

Comment: Great you found it, but Next time please start with creating a [mcve]. In that process you would have removed the style and found that it magicall works. This is called debugging.